# How to resolve AWS ELB redirection issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

We have deployed an application (Tomcat based) to an AWS EC2 instance.  I am able to access the site directly and I can access it via the internal ELB.  However I can't access it via the external ELB anymore.  I get the following error:

```
The page isn’t redirecting properly

An error occurred during a connection to my domain.

This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
```

I have tried clearing cookies and cached data.  No dice.

I have no logs from the ELBv2.  Any thoughts?

Running on Amazon Linux 2, tomcat 7 latest.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your application looks at the "HTTP Host" header and expects *something*, e.g. host.example.com, and if it doesn't see that it tries to redirect there.

Or does the app try to redirect to a HTTPS version of the site? If you are terminating HTTPS on the load balancer and then HTTP (non-SSL) to the EC2 the *app* may not realise that the request was originally made over HTTPS. It may try to redirect to a secure version and goes into a redirection loop. Or something like that.

The best approach is to completely ignore **HTTP Host** and **HTTP vs HTTPS** protocol in the application and only do *relative links* and *relative redirects*.  That way it won't matter what's the ELB DNS name or ELB protocol, the app will always behave the same.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: So in the application I have to tell it what the DNS name is.  Currently I only have http://something.something.com.  Maybe I need to change it to https?

Comment: @AndrewM it depends what you do with that name. Ideally the app shouldn't care what the URL is, not even if it's HTTP or HTTPS, that's all the ELB's or Web server's problem. E.g. links to other pages should be <a href="/somepage/"> and not <a href="http://something.somewhere.com/somepage/">.

Comment: @AndrewM but yes, for start try to set the URL the app expects to be the same as the actual URL that you use to access it. That may help, unless there are more HTTP vs HTTPS inconsistencies and redirects.

Comment: So the URL is set to https in the application.

Comment: I changed it to http.  That didn't help.

Comment: @AndrewM - I'll need more specific details to be able to help. Email me at michael@logix.net.nz if you want.

Comment: Will do.  We actually ended up setting up nginx on the server itself and pointed the ALB/ELB to port 80 instead.